# How to enable Eclipse on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: java, macos, eclipse

I've just upgraded to Yosemite. I'm trying to run the latest version of Eclipse but I get an error saying that Eclipse cannot run on Java 6. Running `java --version` on Terminal gives me Java 8. Why is Eclipse using Java 6?

Comment: There is already a question at StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023956/eclipse-wont-start-after-installing-mac-os-x-yosemite-mac-os-10-10

Comment: I've tried that every answer on that thread, no luck.

Comment: @lapinrigolo I think you need to explain what exactly went wrong with those answers as several of them do work

Comment: I guess because none was the solution I found? No idea otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by downloading the 64bit version of Eclipse.

Comment: Most of the times when you are installing any of the software, we should make sure whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit. Unless the software supports both. That's the normal practice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Java Control Panel installed (System Preferences) if not download the latest JAVA from https://www.java.com (actual exact version is JAVA 7 update 71).
You may then get a working version of eclipse on : 
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
You may need to start Eclipse the first time by "right clicking" and choose "Open" (I don't think the application is signed to be acknowledge by Gatekeeper)...

Answer (score 0):

I could open Eclipse after download this version of java http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Answer (score 0):

As it was said, sometimes upgrading from LUNA to MARS solves the problem - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: @patrix I mean, it said "I fixed this by downloading the 64bit version of Eclipse."

Comment: So this is primarily a confirmation that the accepted answer indeed works? Please have a look at the [FAQ] to understand that on this site there are better ways to show agreement than by repeating an already given answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the system Java 1.6 by a downloaded 1.8.

See: https://gist.github.com/johan/10590467

I'm still stuck with Eclipse: "The JVM shared library ..... does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol", but at least it's detecting the right java.